# googleチームドライブ内の画像ファイルを外部参照する方法について

Tags: google-api, google-drive-sdk

現在googleチームドライブ内のフォルダ内にある画像ファイルを、とあるサイトから外部参照したいと考えております。
※マイドライブでは上手くいきますがチームドライブだと上手くいきません。

試してみたのですが、外部参照するには対象ファイルの共有リンクの設定で「リンクを知っている誰も(外部)が参照可能」の設定にすると閲覧できたのですが、ドライブ上にファイルをアップする際にこの共有リンクの設定をデフォルトとしてアップロードができません。
※アップロード後に手動でリンクの設定は変更することはできるのですが、自動化したいです。

そこで質問なのですが、
①ドライブ上にファイルをアップする際のデフォルト共有リンク設定として「リンクを知っている誰も(外部)が参照可能」に設定する方法はありますでしょうか？

②アップロードのデフォルト設定できない際は、APIでこの共有リンクの設定を入れることができるのでしょうか？　ドライブへアップロードできるようなスマホアプリからアップロードを考えていて、現在APIを使ったプログラムで定期的にファイルIDなどの情報を取得しています。その際に共有リンクの設定ができればと思ったのですが……。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　②のご質問では API に言及なさっていますが、これは適当な方法でアップロードした後、プログラムで自動的に共有設定を変更したいということでしょうか？

Comment: はじめまして！　②のAPIについては仰せの通りで、ドライブへアップロードできるようなスマホアプリからアップロードを考えていて、現在APIプログラムで定期的にファイルIDなどの情報を取得しています。その際に共有リンクの設定ができればと思ったのですが,,,